# What info can a driver get about the function calling open?

Tags: linux, driver, symlink

Does the driver know any information about the application that called open?

I'm using a driver to support 2 similar but different devices. I want to be able to specify which particular device to use when I call open in an application. I am using symlinks for each device linking it to the driver's name so that I can call `open("/dev/dev1"...` or    `open("/dev/dev2"...` instead of `open("/dev/drivername"...` and would like to be able to use this symlink name in the open function if that's somehow possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this doesn't work.  The driver doesn't get any information about the path used to open the node.  Device nodes are specified by major/minor numbers and a character/block type, and that's it.  If you want your different "named" nodes to be distinguishable, presumably they should have different minor numbers.

Comment: Hmmm, that's disappointing. I'll have to look into assigning different minor numbers if it's an option. Currently there's just the one entry in /dev/ for the driver name and the two entries for the symlinks regardless of the number of devices connected.

Comment: What about the file struct? can open not use this struct to figure out the path?

Comment: `struct file` doesn't contain a path, just an inode.  But even if you got an absolute path to the file, that wouldn't get you what you want, which is the path to the symlink that the kernel already expanded and threw away.